# Exporting a shape and a circle

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, animation

[image: Path]

How can I take an arbitrary shape in Illustrator and move all the points outward until they fit a circle. I was looking at blend shapes, but what I really need to export a version of the shape that looks like a circle and another version that looks like this with the exact same number of points. So when they are both exported as an SVG, I can animate between them with web animations.

I also looked at "Add anchor points" to try to match, but the number of points it adds is not controllable.

Comment: You can use the Pen Tool to add anchors to any path. (Or the, uhm, Add Anchor Point Tool - which is under the Pen Tool.)

Comment: Start with the circle. Add points as needed. Then distort circle into random shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example shape has eight anchors, so as long as the circle has eight  anchors, you should be able to make a reasonable step blend to interpolate between the two. Here's a possible method.

1. Draw a circle on top of your shape
2. Add anchors to the circle (Object > Path > Add Anchor Points). This will increase the number from 4 to 8 anchors, i.e the same as your shape.
3. Select both the circle and the shape, and create a blend, edit the blend to make it a step blend and increase the number of steps.
4. Double click on the blend to enter it, and select the circle.
5. Rotate the circle a little until you get a smooth transition.
6. Expand it to bake in the blend as separate paths/objects.

Here's an example showing how much I rotated the circle in step 5 above.

[image]

Comment: I also had to make sure the paths were in the same direction and the starting anchor points more or less in the same place